# Ruby print lines of file after match

Tags: ruby, file, match

I'm reading a file, finding a match, then need to print several lines after the match.  I can't seem to figure out how to print "n" lines after my matches.

```
f = File.open(ARGV[0],'r') 
    f.each_line do |l|
        case l
        when /MATCH/ #Match
            puts NEXT_7_LINES #How do I print the next 7 lines
                    #Would like to print the next 7-12 lines.

        when /DIFF_MATCH/ 
            puts NEXT_4_LINES
        end
    end
f.close
```

I'm not sure how to print lines after a match.  I'm now working with some type of flag / incrementing variable and 'next' after my match but haven't been able to get it to work.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
print_count = 0
f.each_line do |l|
  if print_count > 0
    puts line
    print_count -= 1
  elsif l =~ /MATCH/
    print_count = 7
  elsif l =~ /ANOTHER_MATCH/
    print_count = 4
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice approach, thank you!  I just realized I need to print the next 7-12 lines after the first match.  I don't think your code can be modified to accommodate, can it?  Thanks!

Comment: @twinturbotom To print after first match, add a bool var to indicate if it is the first match. If some certain lines is to be skipped, add another var called "skip_count", just like "print_count".